# software design change from one module to many

Tags: c++, class

I have an existing software module designed as a single class. This software module represents one of the hardware module.
On the new developing product, hardware folks divided this into 4 different modules. Basically, there is not functionality difference. They have changed so many registers, and bits.

How do I design the software for the new product ? The basic idea is to reuse existing code, as there is no functional difference.

Appreciate your advises !

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is called code refactoring.  See the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) for various strategies, books on the topic, etc.